How to use UAMI authentication in Azure synapse spark notebook
We can authenticate ADLS Gen2 source using User-Assigned Managed Identity (UAMI) to authenticate to an ADLS Gen2 source successfully in an Azure Synapse Pipeline. However, we are unable to connect it through Azure Synapse Spark Notebook. can anyone suggest any workaround to achieve this?

can you please any provide any specific error messages you're seeing or describe the steps you've tried in more detail?

At the moment, the docs suggest that UAMIs are "not currently supported in Synapse notebooks and Spark job definitions"
So your best bet would be to use a system managed identity.
Unfortunately, this is yet another area where there's feature disparity between UAMIs and SAMIs in Synapse

Do you happen to know if this is unrelated somehow then? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/credentials?context=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fcontext%2Fcontext&tabs=synapse-analytics

Although you can define your UAMI there, it still isn't usable in every area of Synapse. So for example, I have some ADF pipelines which I moved into Synapse and those were able to utilise my UAMI, but then other areas (such as serverless SQL pool) were unable to work with the UAMI and I had to use the SMI there instead.

Thank you for taking the time to respond!
